# Maximalization of an integral of polynomials over the unit $l_2$ ball.

Tags: optimization, vector-spaces, convex-analysis, lagrange-multiplier

I have a problem where I need to solve this maximization problem,

$$ \max_{\phi \in \mathbb{R}^{p+1}}  \int_0^1 \left(\sum_{i=0}^p x^i \phi_i \right)^2 dx $$
$$ \textsf{subject to}  \quad ||\phi||_2 =  1$$
In particular, I am interested in finding a nontrivial upper bound for the maximum value as a function of $p$. Does anyone have any leads?

Comment: Your objective is just $\phi^\top M \phi$ for some matrix $M$. Hence, it becomes an eigenvalue problem.

Comment: It seems that the upper bound of the maximum doesn't have analytical expression.